# js взять все что идет до запятой

Tags: javascript

У меня есть текст

```
var text = 'Привет, мир.'
```

Как мне можно взять текст, который идет только до запятой?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let result = text.split(',')[0];`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = 'Привет, мир.'
console.log(text.match(/^[^,]*/)[0])
```